# Loading Vim with Hyper on Windows 10 leaves extra characters

Tags: vim, windows-10, git-bash, hyper

I'm using Vim through git-bash on Windows 10 and anytime I fire up a Vim window, it leaves the characters from the screen before it on the page.

Windows 10
[Hyper](https://hyper.is/)
[git-bash](https://gitforwindows.org/)

**Screen before I launch vim**

[image: Screen before I launch vim]

**Screen after I launch vim**

[image: Screen after I launch vim]